# Get all contents from a Tkinter Text widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am writing a script that will take an input from a Tkinter GUI with 2 Entry widgets and a Text widget.

This is just part of my code:

```
root = Tk()
...
text = Text(root)

root.mainloop()
```

What I need is to get all the contents of the `Text` widget.

Answer (score 3):

To read the entire contents of a `Text` widget, use

```
text.get("1.0", "end-1c")
```

Note that with `"end-1c"` you get exactly what the user typed without the trailing newline automatically added by the widget.

Comment: Just an addition, for all widgets where you type, the ```.get()``` method exists. For all of them, such as Entry, and Text, and dropdrown menu as well.